Navigating Ethical Dilemmas: Addressing Forced Authorship and Academic Misconduct in Doctoral Research
I am a doctoral student working in a research group with other students who are also my seniors. They are very diligent and have published some commendable papers. However, my advisor frequently includes students' names in various articles that we have never heard of, without notifying them in advance. These articles often pertain to research fields quite different from ours, and the students are listed as authors in lower positions (e.g., fifth author or further down). The students discover their names on these papers only when they receive submission emails and are left bewildered about their contributions, feeling very upset about the lack of prior notification. Often, the advisor only briefly informs us after the articles are published, saying something like, "I recently collaborated with a certain university, and you were listed as a co-author." Sometimes, the advisor doesn't mention it at all, as if it never happened. Once, when a senior questioned our advisor about this practice, the advisor responded, "Doing this will increase your citation count compared to many ordinary professors," leaving the student speechless.
From the advisor's perspective, this might be seen as a gesture of support and encouragement, but from the students' perspective, it violates academic ethics, and students who have already published good papers do not need to have their academic reputation tarnished by these questionable authorships. Yet, the students, in order to secure their doctoral degrees, are forced to accept this situation.
Unfortunately, I have encountered this situation as well. I received an email from a journal with the title and author list of a paper from a research group at another university, with me listed as the tenth author, my advisor as the twelfth author, and a professor from another university as the corresponding author. I had no prior knowledge of this collaboration between my research group and that university, nor of this paper's existence. I had been discussing my thermal simulation project with my advisor. Realizing that this was a "forced authorship" situation, I speculated that (1) it was indeed a case of "forced authorship," and (2) even though it was "forced authorship," I might not be entirely without contribution, as the paper's topic was related to thermal simulations. Therefore, I decided to remain silent and await an explanation from my advisor.
After several months of revisions, I received an email from the journal stating, "Your paper has been accepted. Please complete your personal information and review the final version of the paper." Upon reading the paper, I found no significant errors, and as I had suspected, the paper included thermal simulations. Additionally, in the "Author Contributions" section, my contribution was described as "writing revisions and reviewing the initial draft of the paper." Considering these points, I felt that my research experience contributed to the paper through my advisor’s work on its "reviewing and revising." Seeing this, I felt that my contribution was acknowledged, and I updated my personal information, including my Google account details. The paper was eventually published, and my advisor approached me, saying, "This is a collaborative work with another university, which is highly relevant to your work."
I thought the matter would be resolved smoothly, but as I continued my research, my understanding of academic ethics deepened. Years later, I realized that my involvement in the paper was minimal and that the authorship was likely a case of academic misconduct. However, this practice seems to be widespread in my research group. Since the paper has already been published, contacting the editor to retract the paper would directly damage my relationship with my advisor and disrupt the collaboration with the other university, potentially jeopardizing my academic career. Consulting my advisor would likely lead to vague explanations, and if he were a principled and serious researcher, such issues would not arise in the first place. Seeking his input would not yield any positive outcome.
Although this paper has no direct connection to my doctoral thesis and my authorship is towards the end, I am deeply concerned about how my acceptance of such authorship might affect the awarding of my doctoral degree. I worry that my degree could be revoked later due to this issue, which would undermine years of effort and severely impact my career.
Therefore, I seek advice on the following:
(1) How can I protect myself and avoid being accused of academic misconduct? I only have the email from the journal and my published papers in thermal simulation as evidence. My advisor has never discussed the authorship with me through social media or email, and he only mentioned it to me in person, which I have no record of.
(2) Will this issue affect my doctoral degree?
(3) How common is this behavior in academia, particularly in research groups, and is it considered academic misconduct?
(4) Should I report this to the university, even though I lack substantial evidence?

This post is similar to my earlier questions

Addressing the Impact of Unknown Authorship on PhD. Students’ Academic Reputation and Remedies

Ethical Concerns of Uninformed Authorship: A Case Study on Student Recognition by Supervisors


but about a concrete case and different timeline.

I have removed almost all meta-information from the question, since Q&A should stand for themselves and this one is already quite lengthy. Note that the timeline of the student knowing about their authorship here is different, so it's not a duplicate of the pervious questions.

Why do you think you could be accused of academic misconduct?

@Dr.Snoopy  From my own perspective, I did not participate in any part of the work, meaning I made no substantial contributions. Additionally, I was not informed before the submission, which violated my right to be informed. All of these actions breach academic ethics, and I believe I do not deserve to be listed as an author. Since these actions violate widely accepted academic ethics, I am concerned that I may be accused of academic misconduct.

The way I see it, these are not actions that you did, but that someone else did, so someone else could be accused of misconduct, but not you.

@Dr.Snoopy   Your points make sense. However, what makes me uneasy is that when I received the acceptance email for the paper, I followed the instructions and linked my academic accounts (Google Scholar or ORCID). To some extent, this felt like actively accepting the authorship. Anyway, thank you for your response!

From my perspective: you've now asked this same question 3 times, gotten the same range of answers on all three, and continue to argue with each in the comments. If you plan to ask until you get a certain answer you want, you could skip the process and just pretend someone gave that answer - it kind of defeats the purpose of asking.

@BryanKrause   As a newcomer, I’ve asked the same question three times in different ways, which is my mistake. I hadn’t figured out how to express my thoughts properly. Based on the responses I've received, I now understand everyone's views on the matter. This will be my final question. Regardless, I appreciate everyone’s answers and attention!

@Dr.Snoopy It would be an uphill battle to convince people you were added to an author list and you had no idea until the paper was published, at least if they're published in respectable journals. While not every journal requires author's consent, you should at least receive a submission email, as detailed, which is when it's your ethical responsibility to decline authorship.

What you describe is a very clear case of scientific misconduct (on behalf of your supervisor) and very likely a violation of the journal's policy on authorship. Whether and how you want to deal with it depends on your relationships with the supervisor and whether you are ready to face the consequences. I would start with politely asking the supervisor (in writing, e.g. e-mail) not to include you as co-author on papers to which you did not contribute. If that happens nevertheless, I would do two things: (1) inform the editors of the journal that your name was inserted without your consent and ask them to remove it; (2) ask your institution's ombudsman for an appointment and discuss the issue.

You are blowing this out of proportion.
In an ideal world, yes, you would have approached the group/your supervisor actively to contribute or to be removed from the author list, or ultimately be removed from the author list by the other collaborators for inactivity.
Academia and especially PhD studies do not happen in such an ideal world.
Students have to learn what the correct academic behaviour actually is, that is the entire point of doing a PhD. Professors and researchers do not always have the time to keep track about the precise contributions of over a dozen (!!!) collaborators. Advisors have to juggle research and helping their students.
Rules for authorship vary wildly between domains, and especially between individual versus collaborative research.
You might want to approach such situations differently going forward. But no one will seriously accuse you of academic misconduct, retract your doctoral degree, or take meaningful steps based on the available information.

Thank you very much for your response! The main issue is that I really didn’t contribute anything, and I had no idea this paper even existed before it was submitted. Getting credited as an author has made me quite anxious.


Rules for authorship vary wildly between domains, and especially between individual versus collaborative research.

I can't imagine a rule where you get authorship because your advisor possibly contributed. That's nonsense and hurts other scientists in other papers that actually contributed.

@Mihail There are domains in which support tasks also result in authorship (see e.g. the CERN collaborations), which appears to come close to the situation here. Whether it actually matches their situation I can’t say.
